# Finding items by simpler ID's on MongooseJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm playing with mongoose schemas. I have 3 items, each one with a corresponding ID field like this:

```
"_id": "508dcb79cb1c8ad910000001","
"_id": "508dcba389e2f32e11000002","
"_id": "508dcba389e2f32e11000003","
```

Is there any default way to process that big chunk of ID to get a cleaner one without having to set up custom id's numbers to just get the last numbers, corresponding the ID?
Or should I use a regex or something to be able to get them by id like this:

```
app.get('/fields/:id', function(req, res) { ; });
```

And access them with `/field/1`, `/field/3` or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification), the ObjectID for a document is made up of a timestamp, a machine id, a process id, and a counter. I don't see a way to take the counter by itself and come up with the ObjectID. Using a regular expression to search the index probably isn't a good idea because you would end up iterating over all ObjectIDs in the index. As pointed out [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions), only simple prefix regular expressions can take advantage of the index. Furthermore, I think multiple documents could have the same counter, e.g. if a write occurred on two different machines to the same collection.

So the short answer is "no". If you really want short IDs you probably should roll your own [sequence numbers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers), use something like [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid), or just look the documents up by a naturally unique index (if your collection happens to have one), like email, username, etc.